# error opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp

Tags: ros, opencv2, wheezy, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

trying to get ros working..
im trying  [this](https://github.com/antdroid-hexapod/antdroid/wiki/Installation) tutorial

now it crashs with following error:

error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory

pi@raspberrypi ~/ros_catkin_ws $ cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4
[100%] Built target compressed_depth_image_transport_gencfg
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/image_transport_plugins/compressed_depth_image_transport/src/codec.cpp:49:33: fatal error: opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/src/codec.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:122: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

can anyone help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225229/error-opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp/) by [g.sart](https://answers.ros.org/users/25706/g.sart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on your version of opencv, this header is meant, i think, for opencv version 3.0 and higher, for example I had this problem when I was trying to follow [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) tutorial because my opencv is version 2.4.8 so i simply delete this inclusion and the error disappear.

---

Originally posted by [ghanimmukhtar](https://answers.ros.org/users/19998/ghanimmukhtar/) with karma: 41 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0